# how many apple Allow to create provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, ipa, sign

I want to create an App-Store-like application. I have an enterprise account.

My question is, if i have 5000 application resign and put it on the MyAppStore, then do I have create 5000 provisioning profiles?

I think if I have too many provisioning profiles, Apple will suspend my account.

There is no other way for resign only with Enterprise Account and don't create provisioning profile for each Application?

Is it possible, in your opinion? What do you propose to this problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by "resign" in your question? No offence, but the way it is worded now doesn't make much sense.

Comment: i want create my App-store,I need to resign any app , for example instagram,whatsApp,... ,resign in here is mean i change sign with my certificate

Comment: Is it even possible to do it without access to source code and rebuilding the app with new provisioning? Not to mention that this sounds kinda illegal. Why do you need this? Maybe an MDM solution would be the way to go?

Comment: do you mean "Master data management" ? what is it? how can i use it ?please explain it

Comment: I meant "Mobile Device Management". You can read more about it here : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/MobileDeviceManagementProtocolRef/3-MDM_Protocol/MDM_Protocol.html . In short, it allows a degree of management of devices in corporate settings, for example.